# Intellij Minecraft Fabric mod exit value -1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, crash, minecraft-fabric

I'm trying to program a mod for Minecraft with Intellij. This is the first time I do something with Java, but I have some knowledge about C#.

The "Minecraft mod base" is Fabric.

When I try to test the program with "runClient", I get the error message "-1" and I don't know what to do with it.

Thank you,

Laurin

crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Hey, that tickles! Hehehe!

Time: 2024-01-18 18:08:13
Description: Bootstrap

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'net.minecraft.util.Identifier net.minecraft.registry.RegistryKey.method_29177()'
    at net.minecraft.registry.SimpleRegistry.handler$zfc000$fabric-registry-sync-v0$setPre(SimpleRegistry.java:691)
    at net.minecraft.registry.SimpleRegistry.set(SimpleRegistry.java)
    at net.minecraft.registry.SimpleRegistry.add(SimpleRegistry.java:178)
    at net.minecraft.registry.Registries.create(Registries.java:230)
    at net.minecraft.registry.Registries.createIntrusive(Registries.java:223)
    at net.minecraft.registry.Registries.createIntrusive(Registries.java:211)
    at net.minecraft.registry.Registries.<clinit>(Registries.java:126)
    at net.minecraft.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:50)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:162)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:470)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23)
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: main
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.registry.SimpleRegistry.handler$zfc000$fabric-registry-sync-v0$setPre(SimpleRegistry.java:691)
    at net.minecraft.registry.SimpleRegistry.set(SimpleRegistry.java)
    at net.minecraft.registry.SimpleRegistry.add(SimpleRegistry.java:178)
    at net.minecraft.registry.Registries.create(Registries.java:230)
    at net.minecraft.registry.Registries.createIntrusive(Registries.java:223)
    at net.minecraft.registry.Registries.createIntrusive(Registries.java:211)
    at net.minecraft.registry.Registries.<clinit>(Registries.java:126)
    at net.minecraft.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:50)

-- Initialization --
Details:
    Modules: 
        ADVAPI32.dll:Erweiterte Windows 32 Base-API:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        COMCTL32.dll:Bibliothek für Steuerelemente:6.10 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        CRYPTBASE.dll:Base cryptographic API DLL:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        CRYPTSP.dll:Cryptographic Service Provider API:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        DBGHELP.DLL:Windows Image Helper:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        DNSAPI.dll:DNS-Client-API-DLL:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        GDI32.dll:GDI Client DLL:10.0.22621.2792 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        IMM32.DLL:Multi-User Windows IMM32 API Client DLL:10.0.22621.2792 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        IPHLPAPI.DLL:IP-Hilfs-API:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        KERNEL32.DLL:Client-DLL für Windows NT-Basis-API:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        KERNELBASE.dll:Client-DLL für Windows NT-Basis-API:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        NSI.dll:NSI User-mode interface DLL:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        OLEAUT32.dll:OLEAUT32.DLL:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        Ole32.dll:Microsoft OLE für Windows:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        PSAPI.DLL:Process Status Helper:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        Pdh.dll:Windows Unterstützungs-DLL für Leistungsdaten:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        RPCRT4.dll:Remoteprozeduraufruf-Laufzeitumgebung:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        SHCORE.dll:SHCORE:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        SHELL32.dll:Allgemeine Windows-Shell-DLL:10.0.22621.2792 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        USER32.dll:Client-DLL für Windows USER-API (mehrere Benutzer):10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        USERENV.dll:Userenv:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        VCRUNTIME140.dll:Microsoft® C Runtime Library:14.28.29913.0 built by: vcwrkspc:Microsoft Corporation
        VERSION.dll:Version Checking and File Installation Libraries:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WINHTTP.dll:Windows HTTP-Dienste:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WINMM.dll:MCI API-DLL:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WS2_32.dll:Windows Socket 2.0-32-Bit-DLL:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WSOCK32.dll:Windows Socket 32-Bit DLL:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        amsi.dll:Anti-Malware Scan Interface:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        antimalware_provider64.dll:AMSI provider :InternalNa:4.0.23.167  :Produc:Bitdefender DFileDesc
        bcrypt.dll:Bibliothek mit kryptografischen Primitiven von Windows:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        bcryptPrimitives.dll:Windows Cryptographic Primitives Library:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        breakgen64.dll
        clbcatq.dll:COM+ Configuration Catalog:2001.12.10941.16384 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        combase.dll:Microsoft COM für Windows:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dbgcore.DLL:Windows Core Debugging Helpers:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dhcpcsvc.DLL:DHCP Clientdienst:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dhcpcsvc6.DLL:DHCPv6-Client:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        fwpuclnt.dll:FWP/IPsec Benutzermodus-API:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        gdi32full.dll:GDI Client DLL:10.0.22621.2861 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        instrument.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        java.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        java.exe:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        jimage.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        jli.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        jna8208888264365467433.dll:JNA native library:6.1.6:Java(TM) Native Access (JNA)
        jvm.dll:Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit server VM:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        kernel.appcore.dll:AppModel API Host:10.0.22621.2715 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        management.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        management_ext.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        mdnsNSP.dll:Bonjour Namespace Provider:3,1,0,1:Apple Inc.
        msvcp140.dll:Microsoft® C Runtime Library:14.28.29913.0 built by: vcwrkspc:Microsoft Corporation
        msvcp_win.dll:Microsoft® C Runtime Library:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        msvcrt.dll:Windows NT CRT DLL:7.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        mswsock.dll:Microsoft Windows Sockets 2.0-Dienstanbieter:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        napinsp.dll:E-Mail-Namenshimanbieter:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        net.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        nio.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        nlansp_c.dll:NLA Namespace Service Provider DLL:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        ntdll.dll:DLL für NT-Layer:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        perfos.dll:DLL für Windows-Systemleistungsobjekte:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        pfclient.dll:SysMain Client:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        pnrpnsp.dll:PNRP-Namespaceanbieter:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        profapi.dll:User Profile Basic API:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        rasadhlp.dll:Remote Access AutoDial Helper:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        rsaenh.dll:Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        sechost.dll:Host for SCM/SDDL/LSA Lookup APIs:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        shlwapi.dll:Shell Light-weight-Hilfsprogrammbibliothek:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        svml.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        ucrtbase.dll:Microsoft® C Runtime Library:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        vcruntime140_1.dll:Microsoft® C Runtime Library:14.28.29913.0 built by: vcwrkspc:Microsoft Corporation
        verify.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
        win32u.dll:Win32u:10.0.22621.3007 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        windows.storage.dll:Microsoft WinRT Storage-API:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        winrnr.dll:LDAP RnR Provider DLL:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        wintypes.dll:Windows-Basistypen-DLL:10.0.22621.2428 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        wshbth.dll:Windows Sockets Helper DLL:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        zip.dll:Java(TM) Platform SE binary:17.0.1.0:Oracle Corporation
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:162)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:470)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23)
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.20.4
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.20.4
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 17.0.1, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode, sharing), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 30202880 bytes (28 MiB) / 293601280 bytes (280 MiB) up to 8556380160 bytes (8160 MiB)
    CPUs: 12
    Processor Vendor: GenuineIntel
    Processor Name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Identifier: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10
    Microarchitecture: Coffee Lake
    Frequency (GHz): 2.59
    Number of physical packages: 1
    Number of physical CPUs: 6
    Number of logical CPUs: 12
    Graphics card #0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070
    Graphics card #0 vendor: NVIDIA (0x10de)
    Graphics card #0 VRAM (MB): 4095.00
    Graphics card #0 deviceId: 0x1f10
    Graphics card #0 versionInfo: DriverVersion=31.0.15.3758
    Graphics card #1 name: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630
    Graphics card #1 vendor: Intel Corporation (0x8086)
    Graphics card #1 VRAM (MB): 1024.00
    Graphics card #1 deviceId: 0x3e9b
    Graphics card #1 versionInfo: DriverVersion=31.0.101.1999
    Memory slot #0 capacity (MB): 16384.00
    Memory slot #0 clockSpeed (GHz): 2.67
    Memory slot #0 type: DDR4
    Memory slot #1 capacity (MB): 16384.00
    Memory slot #1 clockSpeed (GHz): 2.67
    Memory slot #1 type: DDR4
    Virtual memory max (MB): 34673.46
    Virtual memory used (MB): 22060.10
    Swap memory total (MB): 2048.00
    Swap memory used (MB): 78.54
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    Fabric Mods: 
        fabric-api: Fabric API 0.94.1+1.20.4
        fabric-api-base: Fabric API Base 0.4.36+78d798af4f
        fabric-api-lookup-api-v1: Fabric API Lookup API (v1) 1.6.47+82b1bb3e4f
        fabric-biome-api-v1: Fabric Biome API (v1) 13.0.16+78d798af4f
        fabric-block-api-v1: Fabric Block API (v1) 1.0.15+78d798af4f
        fabric-block-view-api-v2: Fabric BlockView API (v2) 1.0.4+78d798af4f
        fabric-blockrenderlayer-v1: Fabric BlockRenderLayer Registration (v1) 1.1.46+78d798af4f
        fabric-client-tags-api-v1: Fabric Client Tags 1.1.7+78d798af4f
        fabric-command-api-v1: Fabric Command API (v1) 1.2.41+f71b366f4f
        fabric-command-api-v2: Fabric Command API (v2) 2.2.20+78d798af4f
        fabric-commands-v0: Fabric Commands (v0) 0.2.58+df3654b34f
        fabric-containers-v0: Fabric Containers (v0) 0.1.85+df3654b34f
        fabric-content-registries-v0: Fabric Content Registries (v0) 5.0.10+78d798af4f
        fabric-convention-tags-v1: Fabric Convention Tags 1.5.10+78d798af4f
        fabric-crash-report-info-v1: Fabric Crash Report Info (v1) 0.2.23+78d798af4f
        fabric-data-generation-api-v1: Fabric Data Generation API (v1) 13.1.21+78d798af4f
        fabric-dimensions-v1: Fabric Dimensions API (v1) 2.1.61+78d798af4f
        fabric-entity-events-v1: Fabric Entity Events (v1) 1.6.0+44c0f8c64f
        fabric-events-interaction-v0: Fabric Events Interaction (v0) 0.7.1+389931eb4f
        fabric-events-lifecycle-v0: Fabric Events Lifecycle (v0) 0.2.72+df3654b34f
        fabric-game-rule-api-v1: Fabric Game Rule API (v1) 1.0.46+78d798af4f
        fabric-gametest-api-v1: Fabric Game Test API (v1) 1.3.1+85d85a934f
        fabric-item-api-v1: Fabric Item API (v1) 2.2.0+d6f2b0844f
        fabric-item-group-api-v1: Fabric Item Group API (v1) 4.0.21+78d798af4f
        fabric-key-binding-api-v1: Fabric Key Binding API (v1) 1.0.41+78d798af4f
        fabric-keybindings-v0: Fabric Key Bindings (v0) 0.2.39+df3654b34f
        fabric-lifecycle-events-v1: Fabric Lifecycle Events (v1) 2.2.30+78d798af4f
        fabric-loot-api-v2: Fabric Loot API (v2) 2.1.5+78d798af4f
        fabric-message-api-v1: Fabric Message API (v1) 6.0.5+78d798af4f
        fabric-mining-level-api-v1: Fabric Mining Level API (v1) 2.1.60+78d798af4f
        fabric-model-loading-api-v1: Fabric Model Loading API (v1) 1.0.8+78d798af4f
        fabric-models-v0: Fabric Models (v0) 0.4.7+9386d8a74f
        fabric-networking-api-v1: Fabric Networking API (v1) 3.1.6+bf1eca544f
        fabric-object-builder-api-v1: Fabric Object Builder API (v1) 13.0.9+06274a474f
        fabric-particles-v1: Fabric Particles (v1) 1.1.7+78d798af4f
        fabric-recipe-api-v1: Fabric Recipe API (v1) 2.0.19+78d798af4f
        fabric-registry-sync-v0: Fabric Registry Sync (v0) 4.0.17+78d798af4f
        fabric-renderer-api-v1: Fabric Renderer API (v1) 3.2.4+78d798af4f
        fabric-renderer-indigo: Fabric Renderer - Indigo 1.5.4+78d798af4f
        fabric-renderer-registries-v1: Fabric Renderer Registries (v1) 3.2.51+df3654b34f
        fabric-rendering-data-attachment-v1: Fabric Rendering Data Attachment (v1) 0.3.42+73761d2e4f
        fabric-rendering-fluids-v1: Fabric Rendering Fluids (v1) 3.0.33+78d798af4f
        fabric-rendering-v0: Fabric Rendering (v0) 1.1.54+df3654b34f
        fabric-rendering-v1: Fabric Rendering (v1) 3.0.13+78d798af4f
        fabric-resource-conditions-api-v1: Fabric Resource Conditions API (v1) 2.3.14+78d798af4f
        fabric-resource-loader-v0: Fabric Resource Loader (v0) 0.11.16+78d798af4f
        fabric-screen-api-v1: Fabric Screen API (v1) 2.0.17+78d798af4f
        fabric-screen-handler-api-v1: Fabric Screen Handler API (v1) 1.3.54+78d798af4f
        fabric-sound-api-v1: Fabric Sound API (v1) 1.0.17+78d798af4f
        fabric-transfer-api-v1: Fabric Transfer API (v1) 4.0.8+e84342304f
        fabric-transitive-access-wideners-v1: Fabric Transitive Access Wideners (v1) 5.0.14+78d798af4f
        fabricloader: Fabric Loader 0.15.6
        java: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17
        minecraft: Minecraft 1.20.4
        mixinextras: MixinExtras 0.3.2
        test: Test v0.1-1.20.4
    Launched Version: Fabric
    Backend library: LWJGL version 3.3.2-snapshot
    Backend API: Unknown
    Window size: <not initialized>
    GL Caps: ERR
    GL debug messages: <disabled>
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fabric'
    Universe: 404
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Locale: de_DE
    CPU: <unknown>
```

When I run it with "runServer", I get the error message "1". I have no logs about this.